# Index matching multiple files

Tags: bash

I have multiple ascii input data files with three columns like so:

File1:

```
00005 3  a
00005 17 b
00007 20 c
00009 2  d
00042 4  e
00042 37 f
00090 49 g
```

File2:

```
00005 3  A
00005 17 B
00009 2  C
00007 20 D
00042 4  E
00090 49 F
00042 37 G
```

File3:

```
00005 3  100
00009 2  200
00007 20 300
00090 49 400
00042 37 500
```

Where the first two columns act like indices and the third column is a data attribute.  From my example files it can be seen that the first two columns don't have to be in any order and some indices can be missing from some files.  I want to compare all three files and have outputs like so:

Output1 (Combined Data):

```
00005 3  a  A  100
00007 20 c  D  300
00009 2  d  C  200
00042 37 f  G  500
00090 49 g  F  400
```

Output2 (Indices with incomplete data):

```
00005 17
00042 4
```

My current (and sloppy) solution involves looking for the file with the most lines, getting the indices from that, finding the indices in the other files, and printing those:

My Solution:

```
cat file1 | while read line
do
  index1=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
  index2=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
  attribute1=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
  attribute2=$(grep "^"$index1" "$index2" " file2 | awk '{print $3}')
  attribute3=$(grep "^"$index1" "$index2" " file3 | awk '{print $3}')
  echo $index1 $index2 $attribute1 $attribute2 $attribute3
done > output
```

However this would give me an output file with 'holes' with the output looking like:

output:

```
00005 3  a  A  100
00005 17 b  B 
00007 20 c  D  300
00009 2  d  C  200
00042 4  e  E
00042 37 f  G  500
00090 49 g  F  400
```

I can still find the good data and missing data by using awk (NF==3 and NF<3 respectively), but I feel like there should be a more cleaner (and possibly faster) way of doing this as I feel that my solution is slow and prone to mistakes (especially the grep find).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

if you can't sort the files, here is one solution

```
awk                 '{k=$1 FS $2} 
  FILENAME==ARGV[1]  {a[k]=$3; next} 
  FILENAME==ARGV[2]  {b[k]=$3; next} 
                     {c[k]=$3} 
(k in a) && (k in b) {print k,a[k],b[k],c[k] > "output1.txt"} 
                      delete a[k]; delete b[k]; delete c[k]} 
  END                {for(k in a) d[k]; 
                      for(k in b) d[k]; 
                      for(k in c) d[k]; 
                      for(k in d) print k > "output2.txt"}' file{1..3}
```

**UPDATE** First solution is not always the best, there is too much code repetition and not general enough.  The following one is better, not necessarily shorter though.  But can be extended to more number of files.

```
awk '{k=$1 FS $2} 
     {for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++) 
        if(FILENAME==ARGV[i]) 
           {a[k,i]=$3; c[k]++}} 
 END {f="output1.txt"; 
      for(k in c) 
         if(c[k]==ARGC-1) 
            {printf "%s", k > f; 
             for(i=1;i<=c[k];i++) printf "%s", OFS a[k,i] > f; 
             print "" > f} 
         else print k > "output2.txt"}' file{1..3}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll test play around with this.  I didn't know you can open and read from multiple files as well as store values in awk.

Answer (score 0):

awk and bash can both do it, but of course awk is a lot easier when talking about columns :)

awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
    arr[$1][$2] = arr[$1][$2] (arr[$1][$2]?" ":"") $3
}
END{
    while(c++ < 2)
    {
        if( c == 1)
        {
            print "Combined values"
            reg = /[0-9]$/
        }
        else
        {
            print "Incomplete values"
            reg = /[A-Z]$/
        }

        for(i in arr)
            for(j in arr[i])
                if(arr[i][j] ~ reg)
                    print i,j,arr[i][j]
    }
}
```

bash (4+):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A arr

for file
do
    while read -r i1 i2 v
    do
        arr[$i1$i2]="${arr[$i1$i2]}$([[ -n ${arr[$i1$i2]} ]] && echo -n " ")$v"
    done<"$file"
done

for i in 1 2
do
    if (( i == 1 ))
    then
        vals="Combined values"
        reg='[0-9]$'
    else
        vals="Incomplete values"
        reg='[A-Z]$'
    fi

    echo "$vals"

    for idx in "${!arr[@]}"
    do
        [[ "${arr[$idx]}" =~ $reg ]] && echo "${idx:0:5} ${idx:5} ${arr[$idx]}"
    done | column -t
done
```

You can call either with :- ./script_name files